# How to update position of markers with “real time gps coordinants”?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've got real time gps positions for a few cars and I want to create a map with updating markers. My code works but it doesn't "update" the markers, instead it adds new objects with new coordinates to the leaflet map. After few minutes my map is full of markers. What I'm doing wrong? Here is my basic concept.

```
var intervalV = document.getElementById("intervalValue").value * 1000;
document.getElementById("setIntervalButton").onclick = startData;
function startData() {
DataInterval = window.setInterval(getNewData, intervalV);
};
```

function getNewData() {
    $.getJSON(server, {
        fun : "GetGpsData",
        userId : "user",
        sessionId : $("#sessionId").val()
    }, fillMap);
}
function fillMap(json) {
for (var i = 0; i < json.devicesData.length; i++) {
    var positions = json.devicesData[i].positions.length;
        var devicepostiion;
        if (json.devicesData[i].connected == false 
        ) {
            var devicepostion = L.marker([json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lat, json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lon], {
                    icon : offlineCarIcon
                }, {
                    draggable : false
                }).addTo(map);
        } else {
            devicepostion = new L.marker(, {
                    icon : onlineCarIcon
                });            devicepostion.addTo(map).setLatLng([json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lat, json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lon]).update();

`}
}`

}

Comment: Since you are only adding markers to the map, you need to delete old markers as soon as they get updated. 
This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912145/leaflet-how-to-find-existing-markers-and-delete-markers

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are running the `update()` on a *new* marker each time. You should store the marker after you've created it; And then run the update function on this same marker-object every time.

This means you have to store the markers outside of `fillMap()`. Also, you need to handle the *changes* in connectivity: when a car *goes* offline, you have to remove the online marker and create the offline icon, and vv.

Answer (score 1):

Making real-time maps is bit complicated by there is a very good library for it here https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime.